# How to enable HTML iFrame in Desktop Application

Tags: vb.net, iframe, web, desktop-application

I am writing a desktop application using vb.net. In that application one screen needs the web information.

We need to get the info from webpage - display as it is on web. whenever the page refreshed or changed the content that should reflect on desktop application also.

I am new to desktop applications. That's why I am not getting which way is better to show the webpage on desktop application.

I thought we could use Iframe to map and place in another website. That way can we do in desktop application also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebBrowser() control and render complete HTML content in a WinForm app. More details here-->http://frazzleddad.blogspot.in/2007/07/working-with-webbrowser-control-in.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display the page, but instead read its contents and display it in the application, you could use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the page and then place the contents into your winforms controls.